# Solving probability problem with complementation approach.

Tags: combinatorics

Problem

> If it is assumed that all $\binom{52}{5}$ poker hands are equally likely, what is the probability of being dealt one pair (i.e. a,a,b,c,d where a,b,c, and d are all distinct)?

I was trying to solve this by complementation.

> Let us find number of ways we can serve hand so that there is no pair. We can select five different denominations in $\binom{13}{5}$ ways. There are four cards of each domination. Thus total number of ways to serve pair-less hands is $=\binom{13}{5}\times 4^5$. To get number of ways to have at least one pair, we subtract it from total number of ways to serve a hand of five cards: $\binom{52}{5}$. So the final probability will be
>
> $=\frac{\binom{52}{5}-\binom{13}{5}\times 4^5}{\binom{52}{5}} = 0.4929$

The solution given was as follows:

> - Number of ways to choose one denomination out of 13: $\binom{13}{1}$
>
>   - Number of ways to select 2 cards of selected denomination: $\binom{4}{2}$
>   - Number of ways to choose 3 denominations out of remaining 12: $\binom{12}{3}$
>   - Number of ways to select 1 card each of selected denominations: $\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1}$
>   - Final probability $$=\frac{\binom{13}{1}\times\binom{4}{2}\times\binom{11}{3}\times\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1} }{\binom{52}{5}}\approx 0.4226$$

Whats going wrong in my solution?

**Update**

As stated by joriki in answer, I forgot to consider other arrangements. I am listing all below:

- all different denominations (i.e. a,b,c,d,e): $\binom{13}{5}4^5$
- two pairs (i.e. a,a,b,b,c): $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}$
- three of a kind (i.e. a,a,a,b,c): $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}$
- four of a kind (i.e. a,a,a,a,b): $\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}$

So the desired probability becomes:

$$\frac{\binom{52}{5}-\binom{13}{5}4^5-\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{11}{1}\binom{4}{1}-\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{2}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}-\binom{13}{1}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}\approx 0.424$$

So this seems to closely match to the solution given. However, I am afraid that I might have missed something because the answer differs in fractions. So please check if I have mistaken somewhere.

Comment: You have still missed a full house:  three cards of one rank and two cards of a different rank.

Comment: aah yess, now its coming 0.42256. Subtracted $\binom{13}{1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{12}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ further from numerator

Answer (score 1):

You ignored the part "where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are all distinct". You counted the hands that contain at least one pair, not the ones that contain exactly one pair.

Comment: yess it seems that I missed some. I have put update at the end of the question. The new answer differs in fraction. Can you please check if I missed something there? (Also it turns out that following complementation approach wasnt really suited here as it seems lengthy. But was trying this approach for practice.)

Comment: @anir: If I understand correctly, the rest of the problem was resolved by N.F.Taussig's comment? Please don't leave a question in the unanswered state when it's been answered. If you don't want to accept my answer because you feel the comment contributed more to resolving your problem, you can ask N.F.Taussig to post it as an answer so you can accept it. If you don't accept an answer, this question will stay in the list of unanswered questions and clutter it unnecessarily.